# PayPal Smart Payments: changing the currency code

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to set up PayPal Smart Payments on a webpage. I'm using the example they give on here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/

If I have `currency_code` set to `USD` it works fine, but if I change it to anything else, such as `CAD` or `GBP` the window won't load. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        'purchase_units': [{
          'amount': {
            'currency_code': 'USD',
            'value': '5',
          },
        }]
      })
    }
  }).render('body')
</script>
```

For some reason this example won't run here on Stack Overflow, but it runs fine on JSFiddle, so I have made two examples with the `currency_code` set differently.

`'currency_code': 'USD'`: https://jsfiddle.net/liquidmetalrob/8y3p52fh/

`'currency_code': 'GBP'`: https://jsfiddle.net/liquidmetalrob/8y3p52fh/1

The first example will load the PayPal window, and you need a PayPal Sandbox account to log into it. So if you want to log in you can use the throwaway account that I just created. Username: `sb-ilukn1050819@personal.example.com` password: `pRKCu9.>` But the important question is why does the window not even load in the second example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/

You have to add the currency code to the script URL instead, and remove it from the JS.

```
<script
  src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=GBP">
</script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        'purchase_units': [{
          'amount': {
            'value': '5',
          },
        }]
      })
    }
  }).render('body')
</script>
```

Note: The `client-id` can be set to `sb` for testing, but in production you use your own one.